# How to integrate codeigniter and PHPExcel?

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel, integrated

always display an error message on my browser:

```
An Error Was Encountered
Non-existent class: IOFactory
```

all classes PHPExcel, i extract on library.

Here it is my controller code

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Report extends CI_Controller 
{
     public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
    }

    public function index()
    {   

        $this->load->library('phpexcel');
        $this->load->library('PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');
        $objPHPexcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('tandaterima.xlsx');
        $objWorksheet = $objPHPexcel->getActiveSheet();
        //Daftar barang (4item)
        $objWorksheet->getCell('B16')->setValue('UTP');
        $objWorksheet->getCell('B17')->setValue('Cross');
        $objWorksheet->getCell('B18')->setValue('');
        $objWorksheet->getCell('B19')->setValue('');
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPexcel, 'Excel5');
        $objWriter->save('write5.xls');
    }
}
```

please help me.

Comment: Did you follow step #1 of the instructions from https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/PHPExcel? And shouldn't it be `iofactory` (lowercase); though if the PHPExcel autoloader is working, you shouldn't need to include that as well as phpexcel itself

Answer (score 5):

Follow the instruction here 
https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/PHPExcel

Please remember to remove the PHPExcel_ part in the class name in IOFactory.php. And change the construct function from private to public

Comment: Also I don't think there is a need to follow the "Updated Guide" link. Just place the PHPExcel.php and folder into the libraries folder

Answer (score 0):

ensure that u save PHPExcel/IOFactory.php inside libraries folder and load it as $this->load->library('PHPExcel/iofactory');

Answer (score 0):

And in some Linux Server, you have to care about case.

`$this->load->library('PHPExcel');
 $this->load->library('PHPExcel/IOFactory');`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this line

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPexcel, 'Excel5');
```

by this line

```
IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPexcel, 'Excel5');
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to place your PHPExcel folder inside `thirdparty` folder. Then create class file in the library folder. There you need to include `thirdparty/PHPExcel` file folder and extend the class. After that you can use it in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Codeiginiter 3 supports Composer to use PHPExcel:

In `application/config/config.php`, set `$config['composer_autoload']` to `TRUE`.

Then you can use Composer to install PHPExcel in Codeiginiter :

```
composer require phpoffice/phpexcel
```

---

Further, You could try [PHPExcel Helper](https://github.com/yidas/phpexcel-helper) to easier handle PHPExcel:

```
composer require yidas/phpexcel-helper
```

> https://github.com/yidas/phpexcel-helper